# Weak convergence implies norm inequality.

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, weak-convergence, quantum-mechanics

When I was reading Mathematical Methods in Quantum Mechanics With Applications to Schrodinger Operators by Gerald Teschl. Link here:
http://www.ams.org/bookstore-getitem?item=gsm-157.

I found in page 56 that if $\psi_n \rightharpoonup \psi$ on a Hilbert space $H$ then
$$\lim\inf \langle\psi,\psi_n\rangle \leq \|\psi\|\lim\inf \|\psi_n\|$$
And I don't know why. It looks like Fatou's theorem, but not exactly.
What am I missing here?

Comment: Maybe it is Cauchy-Schwarz.

Comment: This is a direct consequence of Cauchy-Schwarz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just Cauchy-Schwarz. For any $n$
$$|\langle\psi,\psi_n\rangle|\leq\|\psi\|\|\psi_n\|.$$
Taking the $\liminf$ of both sides gives the result.

Comment: Yes, I forgot the basic, thanks a lot!